# JS DOM: How to stop click event from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get my buttons to stop working when a certain condition is met. For some reason, whenever I get to score 5, on either side, it just keeps going and doesn't even display the score and I don't know why. I've tried using a while loop but it kept crashing. Is there a simple way of just turning it off like there is in jQuery?

```js
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
const pscore = document.querySelector('#pscore');
const cscore = document.querySelector('#cscore');
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 ) + 1; //generate a number 1-3 to find computer choice
    if(choice == 1) {
        return 'rock';
    }
    else if(choice == 2) {
        return 'paper';
    }
    else {
        return 'scissors'

    }
} 

let result; // simpler way of rewriting code?

    rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(computerPlay() == 'rock') {
            result = `The computer chose rock and you chose rock! It's a tie! No change in score.`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            
        }
        else if(computerPlay() == 'paper') {
            result = `The computer chose paper and you chose rock! You lose! Computer Score +1!`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            computerScore++;
            cscore.textContent = computerScore;

     
        }
        else {
            result = `The computer chose scissors and you chose rock! You win! Player Score +1!`; 
            h3.textContent = result;
            playerScore++;
            pscore.textContent = playerScore;

        }
    });

    let playerPaper = paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(computerPlay() == 'paper') {
            result = `The computer chose paper and you chose paper! It's a tie!`;
            h3.textContent = result;    
        }
        else if(computerPlay() == 'scissors') {
            result = `The computer chose scissors and you chose paper! You lose!`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            computerScore++;
            cscore.textContent = computerScore;
        }
        else {
            result = `The computer chose rock and you chose paper! You win!`; 
            h3.textContent = result;
            playerScore++;
            pscore.textContent = playerScore;
        }
        
    });

    let playerScissors = scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(computerPlay() == 'scissors') {
            result = `The computer chose scissors and you chose scissors! It's a tie!`;
            h3.textContent = result;    
        }
        else if(computerPlay() == 'rock') {
            result = `The computer chose rock and you chose scissors! You lose!`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            computerScore++;
            cscore.textContent = computerScore;
        }
        else {
            result = `The computer chose paper and you chose scissors! You win!`; 
            h3.textContent = result;
            playerScore++;
            pscore.textContent = playerScore;
        }
    })

function playGame(computerChoice) {
    computerChoice = computerPlay();
    if(playerScore == 5) {
        h3.textContent = `The score is 5 to ${computerScore}! You win!`;
    }
    else if(computerScore == 5) {
        h3.textContent = `The score is 5 to ${playerScore}! The computer wins!`;
    }
    
}
```

Everything works perfectly except for the 'end game' feature. Thanks in advance for all the help or critiques!

Comment: I don't see an `end game` feature, one thing I want to point out is that you're not passing the event in your `addEventListener`, and therefore no way to intercept.

Comment: One of your issues is that you are executing `computerPlay()` in your else conditions, possibly multiple times. Just do `let compPlay = computerPlay();` and test against `compPlay`.

Comment: Why are you assigning the return of `addEventListener` to variables? It doesn't return anything

Comment: @Phix Yeah i originally created an endgame function thinking that would do the trick for me but it didn't work and i ended up deleting it. I guess i forgot to delete some of it. Thanks for catching that and what do you mean no way to intercept? Sorry, i'm super new.

Comment: @StackSlave sorry, I'm not quite understanding what you mean by test it against compPlay. I'm relatively new to this so i don't quite understand how to test it against something else.Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @JuanMendes I didn't realize assigning a variable to the event listener even returned anything. So i can just delete the variable names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to disable a "click" event

The people in the comments have some brilliant ideas on how you can improve your game. I would suggest looking into that. Although, if you want to prevent click events there are several ways to achieve that.

### 1. Add a disabled attribute to your button.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const button = document.getElementById("myClicker")
  button.disabled = true
}
```

```html
<button id="myClicker">Click</button>
```

### 2. Add a CSS property pointer-events: none;

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const button = document.getElementById("myClicker")
  button.addEventListener("click",function(){console.log("hi")})
  button.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="myClicker">Click</button>
```

The second method is for the situation when you don't need to indicate to the user that the button is no longer interactable.

### 3. Prevent Default event.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const button = document.getElementById("myClicker")
  button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
  })
}
```

```html
<button id="myClicker">Click</button>
```

### 4. Remove Event listener.

```js
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").removeEventListener("Click", yourFunctinoNameHere);
```

Comment: What about removing the event listener altogether?

Comment: @AxelAldrich wow this was incredibly detailed thanks! I don't exactly know what window.onload means but i can take a guess. Also, is disabled a function or just like a built in method? Regardless thanks so much for your help and quick reply!

Comment: np yw. window.onload is just a precaution . in case your script file is not at to bottom of your body tag. So that the page would have the chance to load the button before you execute your functions. It is really up to you which method to use. There are pros and cons to all of them.

Comment: disabled is an html attribute. It is built in to html

Comment: 2 work with me thnxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

and welcome Charles.  So, as @StackSlave mentioned, you keep querying `computerPlay()`, which will skew the results, probably favouring the last `else` (for each button respectively).  This is a logic mistake - but the programme will still run.

You're trying to do quite a lot on the onclick events, and you're not paying attention to any kind of enable indicator.  So.. here we go.  I've seperated the programme into two pieces:

1. Round
2. Ui

The `Round` takes a user-choice, generates a computer-choice, and reports the score.  The `Ui` attaches the buttons to choosing one of the options in the round, generating some output, updating scores and possibly ending the game.  There's also a `reset` on the `Ui` which would allow you to start a new game ;)  Note I've grouped things into objects (vs just functions) since each piece tracks a little state.  I'd likely provide the constants at the top (rock..cscore) to the `Ui` constructor rather than use globals.

```
const rock = document.querySelector(".rock");
const paper = document.querySelector(".paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector(".scissors");
const h3 = document.querySelector("h3");
const pscore = document.querySelector("#pscore");
const cscore = document.querySelector("#cscore");

const NO_PICK = -1;
const PICK_ROCK = 0;
const PICK_PAPER = 1;
const PICK_SCISSORS = 2;
class Round {
  constructor() {
    this.player = NO_PICK;
    this.computer = NO_PICK;
  }

  computerPlay() {
    if (this.computer != NO_PICK) return; //Prevent double play - you might want to throw an exception instead?
    this.computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }

  playAsString(number) {
    switch (number) {
      case PICK_ROCK:
        return "rock";
      case PICK_PAPER:
        return "paper";
      case PICK_SCISSORS:
        return "scissors";
    }
  }

  chooseRock() {
    if (this.player !== NO_PICK) return; //Prevent double play
    this.player = PICK_ROCK;
  }

  choosePaper() {
    if (this.player !== NO_PICK) return; //Prevent double play
    this.player = PICK_PAPER;
    //return computerWinner(PICK_PAPER);
  }

  chooseScissors() {
    if (this.player !== NO_PICK) return; //Prevent double play
    this.player = PICK_SCISSORS;
    //return computerWinner(PICK_SCISSORS);
  }

  reset() {
    this.player = -1;
    this.computer = -1;
  }

  //Return 0: tie, +1 player won, -1 computer won
  playerScore() {
    this.computerPlay();
    if (this.player === NO_PICK) throw "Player hasn't played yet";

    if (this.computer === this.player) return 0;
    switch (this.computer) {
      case PICK_ROCK:
        return this.player === PICK_SCISSORS
          ? -1 //Rock beats scissors
          : 1; //Paper beats rock
      case PICK_SCISSORS:
        return this.player === PICK_PAPER
          ? -1 //Scissors beat paper
          : 1; //Rock beats scissors
      case PICK_PAPER:
        return this.player === PICK_ROCK
          ? -1 //Paper beats rock
          : 1; //Scissors beat paper
    }
  }

  winDescription(score) {
    switch (score) {
      case -1:
        return "You lose! Computer score +1!";
      case 0:
        return "It's a tie! No change in score.";
      case 1:
        return "You win! Play score +1!";
    }
  }

  gameDescription(score) {
    return (
      "The computer chose " +
      this.playAsString(this.computer) +
      " and you chose " +
      this.playAsString(this.player) +
      "! " +
      this.winDescription(score)
    );
  }
}

class Ui {
  constructor() {
    this.playScore = 0;
    this.compScore = 0;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.round = new Round();
    rock.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.rockPress();
    });
    paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.paperPress();
    });
    scissors.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.scissorsPress();
    });
    //Bonus: you can have a reset button that calls this.reset
  }

  gameOver() {
    this.enabled = false;
    if (this.playScore > this.compScore) {
      this.report("You win " + this.playScore + ":" + this.compScore + "!");
    } else {
      this.report("You lose " + this.playScore + ":" + this.compScore + "!");
    }
  }

  sharedProcess() {
    let gameScore = this.round.playerScore(); //Note this might throw if one of the press functions hasn't been called
    this.report(this.round.gameDescription(gameScore));
    if (gameScore < 0) {
      this.compScore -= gameScore;
    } else if (gameScore > 0) {
      this.playScore += gameScore;
    }
    cscore.textContent = this.compScore;
    pscore.textContent = this.playScore;
    //Note this condition isn't exactly what you wrote so you may want to change, but you could do some sort of
    // one has to be +2 over the other (win by two)
    if (this.compScore >= 5 || this.playScore >= 5) {
      this.gameOver();
    }
    this.round.reset(); //Setup for next game
  }

  rockPress() {
    if (!this.enabled) return;
    this.round.chooseRock();
    this.sharedProcess();
  }

  paperPress() {
    if (!this.enabled) return;
    this.round.choosePaper();
    this.sharedProcess();
  }

  scissorsPress() {
    if (!this.enabled) return;
    this.round.chooseScissors();
    this.sharedProcess();
  }

  report(message) {
    h3.textContent = message;
  }

  reset() {
    this.playScore = 0;
    this.compScore = 0;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.report("Game on!");
  }
}

//Start the game - you don't need this ui variable
// unless you want to call one of the methods
const ui = new Ui();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't disable anything. Just add and remove classes instead. Here is a very simple `RockPaperScissors` game. I put a small Library above `// magic under here`. Hopefully you can learn something here:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand, RockPaperScissors; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, success, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      let s;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        fd.append(k, s);
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
RockPaperScissors = function(displayFunc){
  const a = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  this.wins = this.losses = this.ties = 0; this.text;
  this.play = (you)=>{
    let c = a[rand(2)], r;
    switch(you){
      case 'rock':
        switch(c){
          case 'rock':
            r = 'You and the Computer chose "rock". IT\'S A TIE!'; this.ties++;
            break;
          case 'paper':
            r = 'You chose "rock". The Computer chose "paper". YOU LOSE!'; this.losses++;
            break;
          case 'scissors':
            r = 'You chose "rock". The Computer chose "scissors". YOU WIN!'; this.wins++;
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'paper':
        switch(c){
          case 'rock':
            r = 'You chose "paper". The Computer chose "rock". YOU WIN!'; this.wins++;
            break;
          case 'paper':
            r = 'You and the Computer chose "paper". IT\'S A TIE!'; this.ties++;
            break;
          case 'scissors':
            r = 'You chose "paper". The Computer chose "scissors". YOU LOSE!'; this.losses++;
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        switch(c){
          case 'rock':
            r = 'You chose "scissors". The Computer chose "rock". YOU LOSE!'; this.losses++;
            break;
          case 'paper':
            r = 'You chose "scissors". The Computer chose "paper". YOU WIN!'; this.wins++;
            break;
          case 'scissors':
            r = 'You and the Computer chose "scissors". IT\'S A TIE!'; this.ties++;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    this.text = r;
    if(displayFunc)displayFunc(this);
    return this;
  }
  this.reset = ()=>{
    this.wins = this.losses = this.ties = 0;
    if(displayFunc)displayFunc(this);
    return this;
  }
}
// magic under here
const game = I('game'), rock = I('rock'), paper = I('paper'), scissors = I('scissors');
const again = I('again'), res = I('res'), replay = I('replay'), reset = I('reset');
const you = I('you'), comp = I('comp'), ties = I('ties');
setTimeout(()=>{
  rC(game, 'played'); 
}, 0);
const rps = new RockPaperScissors(t=>{
  you.textContent = t.wins; comp.textContent = t.losses; ties.textContent = t.ties;
  res.textContent = t.text; aC(game, 'played'); rC(again, 'played');
});
rock.onclick = paper.onclick = scissors.onclick = function(){
  rps.play(this.id); 
}
function playAgain(){
  res.textContent = ''; aC(again, 'played'); rC(game, 'played');
}
replay.onclick = playAgain;
reset.onclick = function(){
  rps.reset(); playAgain();
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; color:#000; font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#999; overflow-y:auto;
}
.bar{
  width:100%; height:39px; border-bottom:1px solid #777; background:#ccc; padding:2px
}
h1{
  display:inline-block; font-size:27px; margin-left:7px;
}
#score{
  display:flex; justify-content:space-around;
}
#score>div{
  color:#555;
}
#y>span{
  color:#070;
}
#c>span{
  color:#700;
}
#t>span{
  color:#777;
}
#game{
  display:flex; transition:margin-top 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.played{
  margin-top:-38px;
}
#again{
  display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; margin-top:0;
}
#again.played{
  margin-top:-76px;
}
#res{
  width:100vw; font-size:18px; padding:0 10px; text-align:center;
}
input[type=button]{
  flex:1; height:38px; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; border:1px solid #007; border-radius:5px; cursor:pointer;
}
#paper,#replay{
  background:linear-gradient(#679467,#235023); border-color:#070;
}
#scissors,#reset{
  background:linear-gradient(#b75757,#502323); border-color:#700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='bar'><h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1></div>
  <div id='score'>
    <div id='y'>You: <span id='you'>0</span></div>
    <div id='c'>Computer: <span id='comp'>0</span></div>
    <div id='t'>Ties: <span id='ties'>0</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='played' id='game'>
      <input id='rock' type='button' value='rock' />
      <input id='paper' type='button' value='paper' />
      <input id='scissors' type='button' value='scissors' />
    </div>
    <div class='played' id='again'>
      <input id='replay' type='button' value='replay' />
      <input id='reset' type='button' value='reset' />
      <div id='res'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```